# How to correctly define schema for non-carousel category page and also satisfy consumer Google

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

Google mentions [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings) that Carousel markups using `ListItem` with type, position and item is currently supported only for Recipe, Course and Article. So, doing this for other products is not much effective (looking at google search as the consumer).

Google in [another page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#multiple-elements) mentions this:

> A category page listing several different products (or recipes, videos, or any other type). Each entity should be marked up using the relevant schema.org type, such as schema.org/Product for product category pages. However, if one item is marked, all items should be marked. Also, unless this is a carousel page, the marked items should not link out to separate details pages.

Note the statement about usage of proper Schema.org type, like `Product` and *should not link to separate details pages*.

So, for an online seller of shoes, then the category page will probably be like:

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "CollectionPage",
    "@id": "https://www.example.com/cat1/cat2",
    "url": "https://www.example.com/cat1/cat2",
    "provider": {
          "@type": "Organization",
          "@id": "https://www.example.com#org"
      },
    "isPartOf": {
          "@type": "WebSite",
          "@id": "https://www.example.com#ws"
      },
    "name": "Running Shoes",
    "hasPart": [
      {
          "@type": "Product",
          "name": "shoe 1"
      },{
          "@type": "Product",
          "name": "shoe 2"
      },
      ...
      ]
}
```

I didn't use `@id` and `url` here, to conform with Google's statement about no link to separate details page. Don't feel comfortable about it.

Q1: Without these, **how does** this page semantically connect with the schemas of the respective products in other pages?

I didn't define the schema with `ItemList` as the items are not ordered and without `position`, SDTT raises error. (Infact, the above schema too raises error on SDTT with `hasPart`, stating: "Product is not a known valid target type for the hasPart property").

Q2: What is a better way to define this schema, to stay correct as per Schema.org and also not have Google raise errors?

Q3: If we use `hasPart` here for the products, can we on each of the product's `ItemPage` define `isPartOf` to include id-s to this `CollectionPage` (and other categories', if necessary) where the product is listed? Basically, that closes the loop, but as per schema, is that necessary or just one-way declaration (with 'hasPart' in category page) enough?

Comment: I personally go with the Carousel linking out option (Summary page + multiple full details pages). i.e. only mark up the url of the products. But the guides are not very clear.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath I didn't take the approach of Carousel linking out option as that needs `position` for each item, without it GDTT raises error (something that we want to avoid at any cost). And `position`on a category page is also not meaningful, as it's un-ordered. I felt it's deviating from semantic nature of schema.

Comment: What the GDTT says is not schema. It's a clue on what Google is personally wanting. So is their public guidelines.

Comment: @unor Will you have an answer to this query? Or, do you suggest usage of `ItemList` at the moment, with `position` property.